# Start while loop after if statement with look-ahead in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have an array like this:

```
sentence = [NOUN, VERB, ADJ, NOUN, NOUN, ADV]
```

When I loop through it, I want to apply the following rule:

1. Find the first NOUN in the array
2. Add all words to another array `result` until you find a NOUN that is followed by a non-noun

This should result in:

```
result: [NOUN, VERB, ADJ, NOUN, NOUN]
```

How can I apply this simple rule generically?

I tried this:

```
noun_count = 0
for thing in sentence:
        if thing != NOUN:
            print(thing, '<--- I am not a noun')
        else:
            noun_count = noun_count + 1
            print(thing, '<--- Found a noun', noun_count)
```

But this of course only counts the nouns and won't help because I don't know how many nouns follow the second noun.

Can I initiate a while loop after the first NOUN that iterates until there is a NOUN followed by a non-NOUN? Would I need some sort of look-ahead to assess the i+1 element?

Comment: Can you not use noun_count itself to do the job? Simply use `if` construct to select `noun_count = 1` or `noun_count = 2`

Comment: I've updated to a regex problem.

Comment: Try [`\b(NOUN).*?\1(,\s*\1)*`](https://regex101.com/r/cG6tV8/2), or a more precise [`\b(NOUN),.*?\b\1(,\s*\1\b)*`](https://regex101.com/r/cG6tV8/4)

Comment: I've rolled this back to its original form. Changing it to a regex question invalidated both of the current answers. If the answer is to use regex, that's fine, but that should be part of the answer, not the question. I'm also not sure if that's the best answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following snippet should work for you:

```
sentence = ["NOUN", "VERB", "ADJ", "NOUN", "NOUN", "ADV"]
result = []
noun_count = 0
for i in range(len(sentence)-1):
    if sentence[i] == "NOUN" and noun_count == 0:
        result.append(sentence[i])
        noun_count += 1
    elif noun_count == 1 and sentence[i] != "NOUN":
        result.append(sentence[i])
    elif noun_count ==1 and sentence[i] == "NOUN" and sentence[i+1] == "NOUN":
        result.append(sentence[i])
        noun_count += 1
    elif noun_count > 1 and sentence[i+1] != "NOUN":
        result.append(sentence[i])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution not using `regex`:

```
nouns_indices = [index for index, word in enumerate(sentence) if word == "NOUN"]

first_noun = nouns_indices[0]
last_noun = [b for a, b in zip(nouns_indices, nouns_indices[1:]) if b == a+1][0]

result = sentence[first_noun:last_noun+1]
```